# Problem in matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix, vector

I created a random directed acyclic graph using Mathematica. I need to compute a specific function from its adjacency matrix.

$f(G)=\mathbb{1}^\top\boldsymbol{d}^{+}-\mathbb{1}^\top(diag(\boldsymbol{d}^{-})-A)\boldsymbol{w} $

where $\boldsymbol{d}^+$ is the vector of out-degrees, $\boldsymbol{d}^-$ is the vector of in-degrees, $A$ is the adjacency matrix, and $w$ is a vector such that $w_i=\log(1-\frac{d_i^+}{d_i^-})$.

I have tried to code this below. I have added 25 to all in-degrees so that I do not have $\infty$ from the log.

```
     s = DirectedGraph[RandomGraph[{10, 15}], "Acyclic"];
     <del>M = Array[AdjacencyMatrix[s], {10, 10}];</del>
     M=AdjacencyMatrix[s];
     id = VertexInDegree[s];
     od = VertexOutDegree[s];
     <del> wd = MatrixForm[-Log[1 - od/(25+id)]] </del>
     wd = MatrixForm[-Log[1 - od/(25+id)]]
     x=M.wd // MatrixFormA
     Total[x,{1}]
```

Here I run into trouble as my M.wd is not a vector of length 10. Can someone help me complete the code and get $f(G)$?

**Edited**: I have obtained a vector for x=M.wd, but using Total[x,{1}] gives me a vector instead of a number. How do I sum up the elements of x?

Comment: Change (1) `M=AdjacencyMatrix[s]` and (2) ` wd=-Log[1 - od/(25+id)` .

Comment: Don't use MatrixForm in the calculation of wd. It's for display only and adds an invisible wrapper which makes the result unusable in further processing. The MatrixFormA used in the last line is not a standard function. Did you define it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code:

```
s = DirectedGraph[RandomGraph[{10, 15}], "Acyclic"];
M = AdjacencyMatrix[s];
id = VertexInDegree[s];
od = VertexOutDegree[s];
wd = Log[1 - od/(25 + id)];
x = M.wd;
Total@x
```

What makes this work:

1. Do not use `MatrixForm` in calculations, only for final display, since it wraps the expression and leads to a different internal representation.
2. Just use `Total` without a level specification.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, using `MatrixForm` when assigning values will result in something that's no longer treated as a matrix for many functions. You can see the difference directly with the following example.

```
a = IdentityMatrix[2];
b = MatrixForm[a];

FullForm[a]
(* List[List[1, 0], List[0, 1]] *)

FullForm[b]
(* MatrixForm[List[List[1, 0], List[0, 1]]] *)

FullForm[a.b]
(* Dot[List[List[1, 0], List[0, 1]], MatrixForm[List[List[1, 0], List[0, 1]]]] *)
```

In this case, the function `Dot` simply doesn't have a definition for handling inputs with the pattern `MatrixForm[_]`. However, it's often the case that you still want to view the results of intermediate calculations in a readable format. Here are a couple of ways to get around this:

### Change the way you make assignments

You could make your assignments like so:

```
MatrixForm[wd = -Log[1 - od/(25 + id)]]
```

[image]

That way, the correct value is assigned, but the output will still display the way you want to, since `MatrixForm` is only being placed on the output of the assignment, not the assigned value itself.

```
wd
```

[image]

### Change the default behavior of `Dot`

Another option is to directly add the rule to `Dot` to accept `MatrixForm` inputs like so:

```
Unprotect[Dot]
Dot[MatrixForm[m1_], m2_] := Dot[m1, m2]
Dot[m1_, MatrixForm[m2_]] := Dot[m1, m2]
Protect[Dot]
```

This way, when you attempt to multiply matrices that have a `MatrixForm` wrapper, `Dot` will automatically use the contents of the wrapper instead. This behavior will remain for the current session.

However, you need to be careful with using `Unprotect` to change the behavior of built-in functions. It's often the case that you'll just keep running into similar issues down the road and you'll need to keep modifying built-in functions to the point where you'll have a giant unpredictable mess on your hands.

### Other functions

As a relevant example, note that the `Total` function also has different behaviors for the following:

```
u = {x, y, z};
v = MatrixForm[u];

Total[u]
(* x + y + z *)

Total[v]
(* {x, y, z} *)
```

This is because `MatrixForm` will assume a row vector when its input is a 1-dimensional list. So `Total[v]` is like

```
Total[{{x, y, z}}]
```

(notice the extra braces)

This behavior for `Total` is why your last line isn't working properly, because you're trying to compute

```
Total[MatrixForm[M.wd], {1}]
```

To fix this, you could also use `Unprotect` for `Total` and add a rule in, but I wouldn't recommend that route. Instead, the first option is probably safest, even if it means you have to type things a bit differently.

```
MatrixForm[x = M.wd]
```